# Jquery Show After Hide in one Click

Tags: jquery, show-hide

How can show a button after hide of another button
This my Jquery Code i want is Hide the Like Button and Show the Unlike Button.. in one click

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#like").click(function(){
            var id = "<?php echo $NFmsgID; ?>";
            $.post("parse.php",{like: id},function(data){
               $("#like").hide("slow");
               $("#unlike").show("slow");
            });
        });
    $("#unlike").click(function(){
            var id = "<?php echo $NFmsgID; ?>";
            $.post("parse.php",{unlike: id},function(data){
               $("#unlike").hide("slow");
               $("#like").show("slow");
            });
        });
})
```

This is the PHP Code it will select in the database table if the user Like the status or not.

```
    <?php
    require("Database.php");

    $get_button=mysql_query("Select * from likes where UserID='$IDHome' AND NFmsgID='$NFmsgID'");
    $get = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_button);

    if($get==""){
        echo("<a class='button' id='like'>Like</a>");
    }else if($get != ""){
        echo("<a class='button' id='unlike'>Unlike</a>");
    }

    ?></div>
<?php
```

This is the parse.php, here it will add in the database if the user Click the Like, or Delete if the user Click Unlike..

```
<?php
require("Database.php");

session_start();
$IDHome = $_SESSION['sess_user_id2'];

if(isset($_POST['like'])){
    $id = $_POST['like'];

    mysql_query("Insert into likes Values('','$IDHome','$id')");
    echo "<button class='button' id='unlike'>Unlike</button>";
}

if(isset($_POST['unlike'])){
    $id = $_POST['unlike'];

    mysql_query("Delete from likes where UserID='$IDHome' and NFmsgID ='$id'");
    echo "<button class='button' id='like'>Like</button>";

}
?>
```

How can i change Like button to Unlike if the user Click it..
or vice versa..

Comment: What's your question???

Comment: looks fine... what is the problem

Comment: what error you facing? looks like it's correct.

Comment: no error but when im clicking, the hide event only will be trigger and the show is not :( help please

Comment: Here we go.. i edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($get==""){
    echo("<a class='button' id='like'>Like</a>");
}else if($get != ""){
    echo("<a class='button' id='unlike'>Unlike</a>");
}
```

This code will only create 1 link, not both. So when your javascript calls `show()`, the item you want to show doesn't exist. You want to create both links but start only with 1 of them visible. So in the modified code below, we use `display:none` css to hide the link that we don't want to show in the beginning.

```
if($get==""){
    echo("<a class='button' id='like'>Like</a>");
    echo("<a class='button' id='unlike' style='display:none'>Unlike</a>");
}else if($get != ""){
    echo("<a class='button' id='like' style='display:none'>Like</a>");
    echo("<a class='button' id='unlike'>Unlike</a>");
}
```

Comment: i change my $("#unlike").show("slow"); to $(".button").show("slow");
but it showing the same button..

Comment: No, don't use `.button`. After you tried my change, did anything change at all? In your browser, view the html and do you see both links in the source code?